# get table data if field match using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, sql, codeigniter

i have two table

in first table (myfirst)

```
id    website_id   action
 1      2013         0    
 2      2012         0
 3      2011         0
```

in second table (mysecond)

```
id     website_id
 1       2013
 2       2010
 3       2011
```

i am try something like this

```
function getAction() {
        $this->db->select('myfirst.action');
        $this->db->from('myfirst');
        $this->db->join('mysecond', 'myfirst.website_id = 'mysecond.website_id'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
}
```

i want to check `webiste_id` in both table if website id match then get `action`
how can i get this useing `codeigniter` query.
thanks.

Comment: well, you have a typo right here: 'mysecond.website_id' Otherwise, what's your problem?

Comment: I think you need where condition with website id

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $this->db
           ->select('action')
           ->from('myfirst')
           ->join('mysecond', 'myfirst.website_id = mysecond.website_id', 'inner')
           ->get();
if( $q->num_rows() ) return $q->result();
return FALSE;
```

This would return either a result when there are results or FALSE when there isn't.